# SQL Server: get all previous values that are within half year of a month (not in future)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have values such as

```
201401
201411
201501
201504
201508
201606
```

If I select values last six months from 201501, I want to get 201411. If last six months from 201606, then nothing. If from 201508, then 201504.

I have a month column of the varchar form `201601`.

**How can I get the last six months relative to each month with some datatype objects such as datepart functions?**

Comment: Just for us to improve potential answers and comprehension, do you need only one result or return multiple results? (There could be up to 5 values returned if you consider all possibilities.) Does your data is contained on a table or elsewhere? What type is it stored in? (Varchar, char, int?)

Comment: @Lostblue all possible values, range can have many values. If from 201505, then you would have to return at least 201504 and 201501.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option which will reduce record level processing/conversions

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(6))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(201401),
(201411),
(201501),
(201504),
(201508),
(201606)

Declare @Target varchar(6) = '201508'

Select *
 From  @YourTable
 Where SomeCol >= format(dateadd(MONTH,-6,cast(@Target+'01' as date)),'yyyyMM') 
   and SomeCol < @Target
```

Returns

```
201504
```

Comment: Upvoted.  However, I don't like using the Format() function as I've found it to perform horribly when used on a data field.  I prefer using convert(char(6),DateField,112) for this format as it performs much better.  In your answer, you've properly applied the formatting to the variable rather than the column so the performance difference is irrelevant, but I would still recommend getting used to the convert options instead.

Comment: @WesH Yes format is not a good performer, but in this case it is only resolved once

Comment: I have currently used partition and group-by to calculate different ratios over the past 6 months. I get a mistake with a gap-month, a missing month. This approach would solve it with inefficient subqueries so is it possible to have the where-condition somehow within a partition-over-clause: `"SUM(..) OVER (PARTITION BY [OrderID] Order by [CMonth] ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)"` where I am trying to replace the `PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` statement with this specific month approach? Or is it better idea to add zero rows to the data?

Comment: @hhh Bit of a departure from your original question.  Perhaps if you edit the question with some sample data and desired results.   But of the top of  my head, a simple left join to a table of desired dates to "fill-the-gaps"

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I moved the departure from the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617986/sql-server-elegant-way-to-compute-ratios-about-different-windows-such-as-3m-6). My goal is to compute different ratios about different windows (3month,6months). I have currently used GROUP-BY-ID-ORDER-BY-CMONTH-ROWS-directives to filter out rows but this approach with specific month directive may be better. I would be grateful if you can overview it, I am trying to provide sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
where left(val, 4) * 12 + right(val, 2) >= left('201501', 4) * 12 + right('201501', 2) - 6
```

This is rather inelegant.  Basically is converts the values to months since a date.

Alternatively, you can use date arithmetic:

```
where cast(val + '01' as date) >= dateadd(month, -6, cast('201501' + '01' as date)
```

In both cases, you can add a computed column and then an index on the computed column to make the queries run faster.

Comment: The latter selects also the values in the future? How can you bound the future cases away?

Comment: @hhh . . . You can add `val <= '201501'`.  That part is easy.